# Retrieve Proxy IP address C#

Tags: c#, proxy, ip

I need to know what this proxy and in the past I used an IP webservice to get the IP. Is there was some way in C# to get the actually proxy IP address.

If I could just ping somewhere and get the IP that way that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a possible solution [here](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/net-dns-aspnet2-csharp.aspx)

```
protected void DNSLookup(string domain)
{
try
{
//performs the DNS lookup
IPHostEntry he = Dns.GetHostByName(domain);
IPAddress[] ip_addrs = he.AddressList;
txtIPs.Text = "";
foreach (IPAddress ip in ip_addrs)
{
txtIPs.Text += ip + "\n";
}
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
lblStatus.Text = ex.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this method but it only returns the IP address that I have originally and not the Proxy

Comment: what type of proxy are you referring to?